# Packages option breakall not compatible with ctex

Tags: errors, package-options, ctex

I am having this weird issue where the option `breakall` of package `truncate` is not compatible with package `ctex`. Below is the code

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage[breakall]{truncate}

\begin{document}

周一雨
\truncate{0.5 \textwidth}{this is a very long sentence that is going to be truncated to half a text length}

\end{document}
```

This will give you the following error message

> Missing number, treated as zero.  
>                      \unhbox

It suggests the error appears at the line where you want to truncate. However, if you remove the option `breakall` for package `truncate`, everything will be fine, but I need that option to be there.

Could anyone help with the issue? I would really appreciate that! Thanks!